# Control multiple programs without the need of focusing

Tags: windows-10

May I ask, is it possible control multiple programs, at the same time, without focusing on it? (I'm making a software to control many program) And by control I mean send mouse/keyboard inputs in the program.

I know that I can MAKE IT LOOK LIKE I'm controlling multiple programs at the same time if the software that I'm making control them fast enough, but the problem is those programs take like 500-1000ms before it's fully focused.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to still control them without focusing.

If it's not possible can you explain why?

Comment: You're writing software to do something, and you're asking if that something is possible to do. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: yes, and that something is: being able to control multiple programs at the same time, without focusing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is partially yes and no too. because you need to get focus on GUI applications to interact with them. But you can launch any application, it will automatically get focus and you can interact with it. Also console programs which run without a new window doesn't need focus, and even you can run console applications in new window, and redirect STDIN and STDOUT using .NET class `System.Diagnostics.Process.ProcessStartInfo`.